# Remote Desktop to an SMB address from Linux Ubuntu 14

Tags: windows, samba, rdp

I'm trying to connect via Remote Desktop (I need to access IE browser) to an address like `smb://e-xx-10000.mydomain.com` from my Linux Ubuntu 14.

Is there a specific software to do that?

I tried to use rdesktop or Remmina, but there are no options to connect to a `smb://machine`.

Answer (score 0):

When entering the server name, do not include the smb://

I hope this helps